# Get values based on the max of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm struggling to come up with a query to achieve the return data I require from the following table in SQL:

[image: Table structure]

I would like to get Value1 and Value2 for the maximum Order in a given Date and Period range. I have the following query to get the max order number for each Date Period pair in a given range - however, I can't seem to get the Value1 and Value2 for that order.

```
SELECT 
    Date, Period, MAX(Order)
FROM 
    tableName
WHERE 
    ((Date = '2017-02-27' AND Period>= 10) OR (Date = '2017-02-28' AND Period<= 10))
GROUP BY
    Date, Period
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT Date, Period, Order
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Date, Period ORDER BY Order DESC) as seqnum
      FROM tableName 
      WHERE (Date = '2017-02-27' AND Period >= 10) OR
            (Date = '2017-02-28' AND Period <= 10)
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly, I'll mark as an answer as soon as I'm able. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Window function `row_number` for this:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over (
            partition by date, period order by [Order] desc
            ) rn
    from your_table t
    where (
            date = '2017-02-27'
            and Period >= 10
            )
        or (
            date = '2017-02-28'
            and Period <= 10
            )
    ) t
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the top row of a result set, why not use the TOP operator?

```
SELECT TOP 1 [Date], [Period], [Order], Value1, Value2
FROM tableName
WHERE ((Date = '2017-02-27' AND Period>= 10) OR (Date = '2017-02-28' AND Period<= 10))
ORDER BY [Order] DESC
```

Comment: This would be a fine solution if I wanted the data for one Period, however I want the max order and values associated with it for each period in the range.